# Trigger/update data change from child component to parent component in Quasar/Vue incase of child component has list of items

Tags: vue.js, emit, quasar

I am using Quasar to develop my app and still learning.
I have a parent component that has 4 child components as shown in the image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNiCU.jpg).

I can `$emit` child component comp1,2,3 changes to parent component, but I am not sure how I can `$emit' change from child comp 4 to parent. Reason being comp4 receive list(please see list of data in comp4) of data as`props``` from the parent.

I have the following code sample for comp4: `durationOptions` coming as props via Vuex store. I am getting error at line `@click="option.selected = !option.selected"` because of direct Vuex store update.

```
<q-list bordered separator dense no-padding>
    <q-item-label header>Setup duration option and fee</q-item-label>
    <div class="row">
      <q-item-label class="col" dense caption></q-item-label>
      <q-item-label class="col" dense caption>Duration(Hr)</q-item-label>
      <q-item-label class="col" dense caption>Fee($)</q-item-label>
      <q-item-label class="col" dense caption>Discount(%)</q-item-label>
    </div>
    <q-separator spaced />
    <q-item
      clickable
      v-ripple
      v-for="(option, key) in durationOptions"
      :key="key"
    >
      <q-item-section>
        <q-checkbox
          dense
          @click="option.selected = !option.selected"
          v-model="option.selected"
        />
      </q-item-section>
      <q-item-section>
        <q-item-label dense>{{ option.selected }}</q-item-label>
      </q-item-section>
```

Issue is on click on CHECKBOX, I get error `[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation`. I understand that I should not update Vuex store directly.  Or, do I need to update each time Vuex store as and when used clicks on CHECKBOXes? I prefer updating Vuex store on submit/save. Until the submit, how can I have local/temp data change? How can I `@emit` changes from comp4 to parent? Any help me much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can preserve the state on parent and later send everything to the store like this:

**Parent.vue**

```
<template>
<child :options="options" @option-toggle="onOptionToggle" />
</template>
<script>
  data() {
      return {
        options: {
          foo: {
            title: 'foo',
            isSelected: false
          },
          bar: {
            title: 'bar',
            isSelected: false
          }
        }
      },
      methods: {
        onOptionToggle(key, isSelected) {
          this.$set(this.options[key], 'isSelected', isSelected)
        }
      }
</script>
```

**Child.vue**

```
<template>
<div v-for="(value, key) in options" @click="toggleOption(value, key)"> {{value.title}}</div>
</template>
<script>
  methods: {
    toggleOption(value, key) {
      this.$emit('option-toggle', key, !value.isSelected);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: that clearly gave me an answer on how to emit changes from component list items and thanks so much. It still gave to error updating store directly and I ended up cloning store data before passing it to the child component. Although I have maintained duplicate data (store and local copy), I do not have to emit changes (component changes reflected on parent local copy, now I can update store on save/submit).

Comment: You probably need to clone options in a parent component, because now change happens there `this.$set(this.options[key], 'isSelected', isSelected)` - this will give you an error if options sre not coming from 'data', but from 'store'